# uploading file to server

Tags: c#, filestream

```
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"upload");
while (true)
{
    thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, blockSize);

    fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
    if (thisRead == 0) break;
}
```

this code is supposed to write the received file (the file received in bytes stream) to upload folder. the problem is that the code runs with no errors or exceptions but i dont find the file on the pc. is there another way to save the file from the user. it is sent using tcp client and network stream as a byte stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should have a `using` statement:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("upload"))
{
    ... // code as before
}
```

Secondly, if it's running without error then the code *is* creating a file somewhere. It'll be in the working directory of the process. You just need to work out where that is - or specify an absolute filename when creating the stream.

Comment: i guess i have to send the file name and create a file with the same name at the server and write the stream to it.

Comment: @user1065401: Not necessarily - and you definitely wouldn't want to assume that you can write to the same directory structure. The problem isn't the filename "upload" itself, it's the directory you're writing to that you can't find.

Comment: Thanks alot the problem solved by using privilege access on documents while using admin so it is save in documents (i found the file yaaay :D)